# Наложенные элементы и фокус в JS

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Предположим, есть два дива:

```
<html>
  <..>
     <li>
        <div class="first">Квадратное поле</div>
        <div class="second" style="display:none">Поле с кнопочками и текстбоксом</div>
     </li>
</..>

</html>
```

При клике на li у второго div'а display:none меняется на display:inline-block, и наоборот(появляется элемент поверх первого div'a). Почему при нажатии на появившийся элемент, он на нем не фокусируется, а ведет себя так, будто кликаю li. И как это исправить?

Comment: @marinarazdvatri, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: не очень понял что у вас произошло. сделайте пожалуйста пример на  jsfiddle, чтобы было понятно. скорее всего вам  надо проверять e.target в обработчике события показать/скрыть

Comment: Вы используете Jquery? Как назначаете обработчик. В посте вообще нет данных для ответа.

Answer (score 1):

наверное вам событие лучше навешивать не на li, а на элемент .first, вот так примерно:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('ul').on('click','li .first',function (e) {        
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next().toggle();
    });
});
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6yV9N/)

[а тут то что я говорил про e.target](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6yV9N/2/)

Comment: Добавьте что метод "on" появился относительно недавно, в версии 1.7

Comment: ноябрь 2011г, не вижу смысла это упоминать в каждом сообщении.